# Woocommerce -How to set product regular price default

Tags: php, plugins

I am using woocommerce at work for equipment requests, therefore all products I will create will need to be £0. Is it possible to set a default value of 0 for the regular price field on the add product form?

Thanks
Jack

Comment: You can alternatively use a plugin like [WooCommerce Request A Quote](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yith-woocommerce-request-a-quote/) to just remove payment in general.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could run a check on the `save_post` hook, but WooCommerce already has a hook for processing meta where the post type and security checks have already been done.  So using their hook, you just check for a null string on the regular price and set it to 0.

```
function wpa104760_default_price( $post_id, $post ) {

    if ( isset( $_POST['_regular_price'] ) && trim( $_POST['_regular_price'] ) == '' ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', '0' );
    }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'wpa104760_default_price' );
```

Not sure what you are trying to do with WooCommerce, but I had a client use
http://a3rev.com/shop/woocommerce-quotes-and-orders/ to switch from a normal price/cart store to a "request for quote" catalog.

Edit: While the above will save a 0 as the price any time a product is created/updated, the following will always allow a product to be purchasable regardless of the price:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', '__return_TRUE');
```

To totally remove the "sale" flash, simply unhook it from its action hook:

```
function woocommerce_remove_stuff(){
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash', 10 );
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'woocommerce_remove_stuff');
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I have tried the above function but it doesn't seem to allow the product to be added to the cart. I am trying to create an equipment request system where logged in users can add equipment (that has no price) to the cart and place an "order" for these items. The users are employees of my company and the equipment is already owned by the company.

Comment: I thought that a free product could be added to the cart. You could also try overriding the `woocommerce_is_purchasable` filter to always be true.

Comment: When I manually type 0 into price I can add it to the cart but using the above function and leaving it blank does not show the add to cart button but is displaying the sale icon. How would I go about overriding the woocommerce_is_purchasable filter?

Comment: My code was for when you create and/or edit a product and don't fill out the price...so a default price. It will automatically set the price to 0 but only when you save a product. It has no bearing on the front-end except that which is effected by having a zero price.  Again, I think `woocommerce_is_purchasable` might be the answer.

Comment: add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'woocommerce_is_always_purchasable');

function woocommerce_is_always_purchasable(){
return true;
}

Comment: Thanks, the above has solved it but for some reason the sale icon is being displayed. Is it possible to disable the sale function completely as this is something I will not be using.

Comment: Check my edit to remove the sale flash.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this problem, this function sets the product regular price and sale price to 0 after updating the product:

```
function set_default_price( $post_id, $post ) {

    if ( isset( $_POST['_regular_price'] ) && trim( $_POST['_regular_price'] ) == '' ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', '0' );
    }

if ( isset( $_POST['_sale_price'] ) && trim( $_POST['_sale_price'] ) == '' ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_sale_price', '0' );
    }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'set_default_price' );
```

The line of code below make new product purchasable, you can use this code for new products:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', '__return_TRUE');
```