# Show add to cart button and quantity field when no price is entered

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am using woocommerce for a sample site, meaning a place where people can order samples of products for free. The products themselves are not sold on this site.

If I leave the price field blank, the add to cart, quantity field and price don't show up. If I enter 0 for the price, then those will show up.

I would like for my client to not have to enter 0 for the price. So my goal is to either show the add to cart button and quantity field when no price is entered(preferred), or if there is a way to pre-populate the price field with 0 on every existing and newly created product.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the following?

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/104783/77202

From the answer above the following will always set the price to default to 0 when creating/updating a product

```
function wpa104760_default_price( $post_id, $post ) {

    if ( isset( $_POST['_regular_price'] ) && trim( $_POST['_regular_price'] ) == '' ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_regular_price', '0' );
    }

}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'wpa104760_default_price' );
```

Again from the answer above you and the answer to your question, to always allow the product to be purchasable regardless of price existing:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', '__return_TRUE');
```

Both of these pieces of code can be added to your functions.php file.

Credit to [helgatheviking](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/104783/77202)

Comment: Awesome! You rock, man! This is exactly what I was looking for. Works like a charm. Thank you!

Comment: Crap, at first I had thought this worked. but is throwing a bunch of errors. When I try to add a product to the cart, it errors out, then if I re-save an existing product, I get a fatal error. Gonna have to keep searching on this one.

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: if I add the filter to always make a product purchasable, I get the following warnings:

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /path/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart-totals.php on line 234

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /path/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-discounts.php on line 88

If I add the function you provided, see my next comment for fatal error

Comment: Hmm, error is too long to put in a comment. So I will put as an answer, and hopefully nobody will down vote it.

Comment: Okay so just tested on a dev site. I get the errors for the function you are getting but the filter seems to be working fine for me. Where exactly in the process of checking out do you see the error? What version of php are you running? Also remove the answer now. Dont need to see it anymore. :)

Comment: I get the warnings on the individual product page after hitting the add to cart button. It adds it to my cart, and displays the message and link to view cart though. PHP version: 7.1.14
Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Oh and by display the message I meant the woocommerce message saying the product has been added to the cart. It displays the warning at the very top of the page above the header.

Comment: Could be a PHP issue, take a look at this thread on the github page: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/12690